# Conditional Forcasting with VAR model in python

Tags: python, r, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

I am using VAR model to forecast multivariate time series with lag 2. I have three features, and would like to forcast several timestamps forward. Instead of forcasting all the three features, I actually know the values of two of the features, and would like to forcast only one feature.

If I wanted to forcast all the three features 5 timestamps a head, I could have done that as follows (this is a toy example):

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR    
data=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['1959-06-01','1959-06-02','1959-06-03','1959-06-04']\
                   ,'a':[1,2,3,5],'b':[2,3,5,8],'c':[3,4,7,11]})
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
model = VAR(data)
results = model.fit(2)
results.forecast(data.values[-2:], 5)
```

Note that `data` is

```
            a  b   c
Date                
1959-06-01  1  2   3
1959-06-02  2  3   4
1959-06-03  3  5   7
1959-06-04  5  8  11
```

And the forecast gives me

```
array([[   8.01388889,   12.90277778,   17.79166667],
       [  12.93113426,   20.67650463,   28.421875  ],
       [  20.73343461,   33.12405961,   45.51468461],
       [  33.22366195,   52.98948789,   72.75531383],
       [  53.15895736,   84.72805652,  116.29715569]])
```

Let's say I knew that the next 5 values for `a` should have actually been `8,13,21,34,55` and the next 5 values for `b` should have been `13,21,34,55,89`. Is there a way to incorporate that into the model in `statsmodels.tsa` (or any other python package) to forecast only the 5 values of `c`? I know that `R` has such an option, by incorporating "hard" conditions into `cpredict.VAR`, but I was wondering if this can be done in python as well.

The above is a toy example. In reality I have several dozens of features, but I still know all of them and would like predict only one of them using VAR model.

Comment: This is currently not directly supported. (No statsmodels contributor ever looked at this case, AFAIK). In which R package is cpredict.VAR.

Comment: @user333700 thanks for letting me know. The R package that I mentioned is the one that described in the section "Conditional Forecasting" (page 403) in https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=563d2dbe6225ff39e98b4567&assetKey=AS%3A292924211384321%401446849982801.

Comment: S+FinMetrics is a commercial S-plus package, AFAICS. I don't know how difficult it would be to implement it on top of statsmodels VAR or the statespace version VARMAX.

Comment: Isn't this a bit similar to Impulse Response analysis? Python statsmodels has modules that deal with it (but I haven't used them myself).

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue when solving this problem. This is a makeshift method to accomplish what you are asking.

```
prediction = model_fit.forecast(model_fit.y, steps=len(test))
predictions = prediction[:,0]
```

`
Where 0 in the prediction[:,0] refers to the column that contains the desired forecasting value.